# Method of multiple open .pkpass in iPhone

Tags: iphone, email, safari, wallet, passkit

A very short question:

Any method to open **more than one** [`.pkpass`](http://fileinfo.com/extension/pkpass) file **in one action** at iPhone devices?

Comment: From an app, yes - it's all in the documentation.

Comment: @PassKit It is possible using with safari mobile to handle the passes  "request register" on screen status?